# Recall previous command in the RubyMine console

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, rubymine, rubymine-7

In the RubyMine consoles, like the one that appears in RubyMine 7 while debugging, how do you recall the previous command or line you typed? Something similar to pressing the up arrow in a conventional terminal or console.

Comment: Hi this is frustrating, did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 4):

- The history of commands can be accessed similar to any conventional terminal or console :- **using the up and down arrows** to scroll through the history.
- The commands history size limit can be specified in : **File|Settings|Editor - "Console commands history size"**
- Scrolling through console history with the up key in any command line environment can be pretty tedious. **option-command-E**, can show you your entire commands history.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. When I am inside the terminal it works just fine, but when I enter the Rails console. So I have to exit Rubymine and open the Windows CMD to play with the console.

Answer (score 1):

Looking into RubyMine 7.0 Doc

https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/using-consoles.html

In an interactive console, you can:

- Type commands in the lower pane of the console, and press Enter to
  execute them.
- Results are displayed in the upper pane. Use basic code    completion
  Ctrl+Space.
- **Use Up and Down arrow keys to scroll through    the history of
  commands, and execute the required ones.**
- Load source code fom the editor into console.
- Use context menu of the upper pane to copy all output to the
  clipboard, compare with the current contents of the clipboard, or
  remove all output from the console.
- Use the toolbar buttons to control your session in the console.
  Configure color scheme of the console to meet your preferences.
  Refer to the section Configuring Color Scheme for Consoles for
  details.